# Using RealmSwift to save an one-to-many relationship object

Tags: swift, realm, swift4, swift4.2

I'm coming from a Ruby on Rails-like data structure in terms of relationships.

So in Rails: Foo has many Bars and Bar has one Foo.

Going through the RealmSwift docs, I came up with this, I think:

```
class Foo: Object {
  // other props
  var bars = List<Bar>() // I hope this is correct
}

class Bar: Object {
  // other props
  @objc dynamic var foo: Foo?
}
```

If the above is corrct, I struggle to know how to create this relationship object.

```
// I need to create Foo before any Bar/s
var foo = Foo()
foo.someProp = "Mike"

var bars = [Bar]()
var bar = Bar()
bar.someProp1 = "some value 1"
bars.insert(bar, at: <a-dynamic-int>)
```

This is where I am at a full stop:

```
// Create Foo
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(foo)
  // But.... I need to append bars, how?
}

try! realm.write {
   for bar in bars {
      // realm.add(bar)
      // I need to: foo.append(bar) but how and where?
   }
}
```

In the end, I should be able to `foo.bars` to see an array of `bars` and `bar.foo` to get `foo`

`foo` and `bar` have not yet been created so do not know how to chain the lot to save at once. Possible? How? If you are providing an answer, can you post a reference to the doc for future reference? That would count as an answer for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
class Foo: Object {
    // other props
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    let bars = List<Bar>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Bar: Object {
    // other props
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    let foo = LinkingObjects(fromType: Foo.self, property: "bars")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.id = "somethingUnique"
foo.someProp = "Mike"

let bar = Bar()
bar.id = "somethingUnique"
bar.someProp1 = "some value 1"

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(foo)
    realm.add(bar)
    foo.bars.append(bar)
}

let anotherBar = Bar()
anotherBar.id = "somethingUnique"
anotherBar.someProp1 = "some other value"
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(anotherBar)
    foo.bars.append(anotherBar)
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
var currentBars: List<Bar>()
if let findFoo = realm.object(ofType: Foo.self, forPrimaryKey: "someUniqueKey") {
    currentBars = findFoo.bars
    // to filter
    if let specificBar = currentBars.filter("id = %@", id) {
        // do something with specificBar
    }
}
```

To get foo from bar:

```
if let bar = realm.object(ofType: Bar.self, forPrimaryKey: "theUniqueID") {
    if let foo = bar.foo.first {
        // you have your foo
    }
}
```

If I'm understanding your comment correctly:

```
// already created foo
for nonRealmBar in nonRealmBars {
    // Note: you could also use realm.create
    let bar = Bar()
    bar.id = nonRealmBar.id
    bar.someProp = nonRealmBar.someProp
    // fill in other properties;
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(bar)
        foo.bars.append(bar)
    }
}
```