# Realm in Swift relationship no add rows

Tags: swift, realm

I am bulding app with relationship one to many. I can't add rows in my class.

```
class Bank : Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var allCash = 0
    let persons = List<Person>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}

class Person : Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var cash = 0

    let parent = LinkingObjects(fromType: Bank.self, property: "person")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"

    }

    func incrementID() -> Int {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return (realm.objects(TransactionType.self).max(ofProperty: "id") as Int? ?? 0) + 1
    }

}
```

Save date in base

```
lat bank = Bank()
let persons = bank.persons
let parent = realm.objects(Bank.self).first!

try! realm.write {
    for person in persons {
        let newPerson = Person()
        newPerson.cash = person[cashTextField.text!] as! Int
        newPerson.id = person.incrementId()
        realm.add(newPerson)
        parent.persons.append(newPerson)   
    }    
}
```

When I pressed buton no errors and no added rows. I tried also this syntax and see row but it is with no relationship.

```
try! realm.write {
        let newPerson = Person()
        newPerson.cash = Int(cashTextField.text!)
        realm.add(newPerson)
}
```

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725688/using-realmswift-to-save-an-one-to-many-relationship-object/54727135#54727135) to see if it helps. You have several problems in your implementation. One thing you won't find in that answer is that you need to change `property: "person"` to `property: "persons"`. Notice it's plural in Bank.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new person to an existing Bank or a new Bank? Also, you can use auto-incrementing numerical id's but you may find it easier to use `@objc dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString`, then you don't have to worry about incrementing.

Comment: You'll need to expand this question to tell us exactly what you're trying to do. It really isn't clear. When do you want to add data, and what is that data? Your first example will do nothing: (1) you're creating a new `Bank` object which will have no `persons` associated with it, then (2) you're iterating through each person associated with that bank (i.e. nothing) and creating a new person (which is nonsense). I think your second attempt is closer, but you need to step back and think about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I am trying add person to existing Bank. And in my intention is one bank and many people. W have bank and this bank have money. The person add money or takes money from bank.This is my first project with realm and I don't know the relationship is correct which I showed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question really isn't too far off so we'll tighten it up a bit and get you going.

First, let's define customer and bank classes

```
class CustomerClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var customer_id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var cash = 0.0
    let parent = LinkingObjects(fromType: BankClass.self, property: "customerList")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "customer_id"
    }
}

class BankClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var bank_id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var cash_balance = 0.0
    let customerList = List<CustomerClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "bank_id"
    }
}
```

as you can see there's a relationship that's defined as many to many; the bank can have multiple customers and a customer can have multiple banks. That works in this scenario and will allow you to add a customer to a bank and have the reverse relationship automatically created.

Then a function to add a customer to the first bank in the list. If there are multiple banks you would want to filter to get the bank you want to add the customer to but for this example, we'll just assume there's only one bank

```
func addCustomerToFirstBank() {
    if let realm = gGetRealm() {
        let bankResults = realm.objects(BankClass.self)
        if let firstBank = bankResults.first {
            let customerToAdd = CustomerClass()
            customerToAdd.cash = 50
            try! realm.write {
                firstBank.customerList.append(customerToAdd)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note:

For brevity, we have a singleton that returns a realm when gGetRealm is called()

We are using a technique where swift will create a unique identifier for each bank and customer as their id. The key to the id is that it must be unique but it doesn't really matter what it is so if you are more comfortable using an incrementing index, that's fine as well.

Comment: I don't know why you use gGetRealm - changed to Realm() and it is work

Comment: @Martix I addressed why I used gGetRealm in my answer, toward the end - it's a singleton I use to get a reference to Realm throughout my app. Makes the code a bit cleaner.